# Swift 3 OSX app textfield and pop button to the clipboard

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm new with Swift, but what I would like to do basically is
now what the user selected for Q1 : Q 4,
if for example the user selected Yes at Q1, no to Q2 then I would like to add a string to the clipboard :

> Q1 : Question one is there : Yes 
>   Q2 : Question two is here : No

and last thing from the button "done" 
I would like to added to the previous clipboard and copy what ever the text is on the first textfield and put all together into the clipboard

[image: UI]

```
 // Case Questions 


    @IBOutlet weak var qUestionOne: NSPopUpButton!


    @IBOutlet weak var qUestionTwo: NSPopUpButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var qUestionTree: NSPopUpButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var qUestionFor: NSPopUpButton!


    // CaseNote

    @IBOutlet weak var cAseNoteTextField: NSTextField!

    // Draft

    @IBOutlet weak var dRaftNote: NSTextField!


    // buttons

    @IBAction func dOneButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you're adding each individual field to the clipboard? It would be simpler to create a string from all the fields' values when the Done button is clicked and then add that string to the pasteboard with `NSPasteboard.general().declareTypes([NSPasteboardTypeString], owner: nil)`
`NSPasteboard.general().setString(combinedString, forType: NSPasteboardTypeString)`

Comment: Yes that make more sense alright thank, will try this tomorrow thank you